# PHP Pagination not displaying

Tags: php, pagination

I have a search code that uses pagination to display results but the pagination is not displaying or working. I want such that 7 results are displayed per page view but cant seem to get it to work.

Kindly help me point out the issue and i need to understand why the pagination isn't working even though the search query is.

Below are my codes:

```
if (isset($_GET["mainSearch"]))
{
  $condition = '';
  $mainSearch = SQLite3::escapeString($_GET['mainSearch']);
  $searchquery = $_GET['mainSearch'];
  $query = explode(" ", $searchquery);
  $perpageview = 7; // amount of results to display per page

  if ($_GET["pageno"])
  {
      $page = $_GET["pageno"];
  }
  else
  {
      $page = 1;
  }

  $frompage = $page*$perpageview-$perpageview;

  $csql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR answer LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
  $cret = $db->querySingle($csql);

  $pagecount = ceil($cret/$perpageview);

  if ($cret == 0)
  {
      echo  "<div class='sug'>Did you mean to ask any of this?</div>";

      $sortFullMatch = "(CASE WHEN question LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($searchquery)."%' OR answer LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($searchquery)."%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fullmatch";

      foreach ($query as $word)
      {
          $x++;
          if ($x == 1)
          {
              $condition .= "question LIKE '%$word%'";
          }
          else
          {
              $condition .= "OR question LIKE '%$word%'";
          }
      }
      $order = " ORDER BY fullmatch DESC, quiz_id DESC ";
      $condition_q = "SELECT *,". $sortFullMatch ." FROM questions WHERE ".$condition.' '.$order.' LIMIT '.$frompage.','.$perpageview;
      $result = $db->query($condition_q);
      $concount = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE " . $condition;
      $resultCount = $db->querySingle($concount);
      $pagecount = ceil($resultCount/$perpageview);
      if ($resultCount > 0)
      {
            if ($result)
            {
                while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
                {

                    foreach($query as $text) 
                    {
                        $wording = str_replace($text, "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: #1a0dab;'>".$text."</span>", $row['answer']);
                    }

                    echo '<div class="quesbox_3">
                    <div class="questitle">
                    <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quesanswer">'.$wording.'</div>
                    </div>';
                }
                     echo '<div class="modulelinks">
                        <div class="mfound">Founded: <span>'.$founded.'</span></div>
                        <div class="mowned">Ownd By: <span>'.$owner.'</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

               // <div class="mavailable">Available for Export Loan: <span>'.$available.'</span></div>
                }
                echo '<div class="page_num">';
                for ($i=1; $i <= $pageount; $i++) 
                {
                    echo '<a href="searchresult.php?mainSearch='.$mainSearch.'&pageno='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
                }
                    echo '</div>';
            }
      }
  }
  else
  {
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$searchquery%' or answer LIKE '%$searchquery%' LIMIT '$frompage','$perpageview'");
        $bsql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM banks WHERE bname LIKE '%$searchquery%' or bankbrief LIKE '%$searchquery%' LIMIT 1");
        $sqlcount = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR answer LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
        $retCount = $db->querySingle($sqlcount);
        $pagecount = ceil($retCount/$perpageview);
        $ret = $sql->execute();
        $bret = $bsql->execute();
        while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
        {   
            $wording = str_replace($searchquery, "<span style='font-weight: bold; color: #1a0dab;'>".$searchquery."</span>", $row['answer']);

            echo '<div class="quesbox_3">
            <div class="questitle">
            <h2>'.$row["question"].'</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="quesanswer">'.$wording.'</div>
            </div>';
        }
    ?>
//for page links
    <div class="page_num">
    <?php
    for ($i=1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) 
    {
       echo '<a href="searchresult.php?mainSearch='.$mainSearch.'&pageno='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

What could be the issue with this? Thanks.

Comment: `cant seem to get it to work`, `pagination isn't working` is not a way to describe your problem. What are the actual results you get?

Comment: empty. The results display but pagination links don't show

Comment: maybe the script halts before (error not catched). you should try with some sensible debug before posting here, as your issue can only be explained by something wrong with $pagecount value (NULL or 0) or a script error. try to call ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout') at the beginning of the script, so that script error are displayed on screen (instead of error log).